# python design choice - if condition inside loop that is run for many iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop like -

```
for x in range(int(1e9)):
    #lot of code
```

Now based on user input, I need to make a small change to the code inside this loop like this.

```
if user_input == 'hi':
    for x in range(int(1e9)):
        #small change
        #lot of code
else:
    for x in range(int(1e9)):
        #lot of code
```

However, `lot of code` is being repeated unnecessarily, creating redundancy.

One option is to have the `if condition`inside the `for loop`. But this would increase the execution time considerably due to many iterations (have timed it and verified).

Another option I thought of is creating a function which does `lot of code`. However, `lot of code` contains a lot of variables present outside this for loop. This function would then have many many parameters, which I do not want.

What is the best way to organize this code? Thanks!

Comment: Base on what exactly the "small change" is.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori The user input to the code.

Comment: There's no optimal solution. You could put `lots of code` in a function and use global variables instead of parameters.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I see thanks. I'll take a look at Code Review.

Comment: You might could also work with a class, respective an object, which has all the variables. Then you could just feed the one object to `lots of code` which can then access the attributes of the object. Not sure if that is in the sense of the PEP-20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a function that uses `**kwargs` instead of declaring all the parameters, this will give you a dictionary with all the parameters as keys

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['param1']) # 1
    print(kwargs['param2']) # asd

func(param1=1, param2='asd')
```